# javascript: json data parsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, highcharts

Requirement is data is to be pulled through JSON and give it to chart.
Data need to be int the form of

> var dataArray = [{data:[]},{data:[]}];

The code for getting JSON data on clientside is like below:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Default.aspx/SendJsonUpadtes",
                    data: "{}",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        $("#Result").text(msg.d);
                        alert(msg.d);
                   }
                });
```

Asp.net Serverside code:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = false)]
    public static string SendJsonUpadtes()
    {
        return JSONFromCSV();

    }

    public static string JSONFromCSV()
    {
        //var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"D:\logs\data.csv"));
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\logs\electricity\data.csv");
        object[,] data = new object[lines.Count(), 2];
        int i = 0;
        string jsonStr = "[";
        lines.ToList().ForEach(line =>
        {
            jsonStr += "["+line+"]";
            i++;
            if (i < lines.Count())
                jsonStr += ",";
        });
        jsonStr += "]";
        return jsonStr;
    }
```

Data is recieved in string form:

> "[[10,20],[20,30],[30,40]]"

I need to parse it to make it var dataArray = [{data:[]},{data:[]}];

How can i do it using Javascript or JQuery!
Any other better ideas?

Comment: Exactly like you posted it... where is the problem? Please be more specific. I have the feeling this does not have anything to do with parsing JSON.

Comment: So you have JSON encoded data inside of JSON encoded data? Why? Ideally `msg.d` would just be an array, not a string. I recommend to fix that on the server side. The other part of your question is still valid of course. *edit:* uh, don't build JSON manually...  use a library to convert data to JSON and let it be converted by the server (don't know how this works in that language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var dataArray = [];
$.each(msg.d, function(index, value) {
  dataArray.push({data : value});
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nscy3/)

Comment: data is in string format "[[10,20],[20,30],[30,40]]"

Comment: See this will work for you http://jsfiddle.net/Nscy3/4/

Comment: Is the fiddle demo not working or its your code? Fiddle is definitely working as you can see in the console!

Comment: fiddle, i can see.but i dont see output, may be because i have IE 9.

Comment: Yes, try a different browser once..

Comment: i tried it in my code, strangely i see this on alert(dataArray): [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: may be something like typecasting is required, but i can see the array values properly on watch window

Comment: @Seenu: This is to be expected. `alert` converts the argument to a string and the default string representation of an object is `"[object Object]"`. So you have three objects in your array. `alert` is mostly unsuitable for debugging, use `console.log` instead.

Comment: Thanks guys! Worked  --> series: [{data: $.parseJSON(msg.d)}]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to modify your data array.

```
var data = [[10,20],[20,30],[30,40]];

var dataArray = data.map(function(element) {
                            return { "data" : element }
                         });
```